# Missing folder errors during capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm not sure I understand the error messages I'm getting while attempting to deploy my rails app with capistrano. The deploy is failing because of some missing directory (more specifically: images, stylesheets and javascript) but I'm not sure why these directories are being searched for in the public directory of the release directory. These folders should be in the assets directory of my app directory, but capistrano searching the public folder of the release folder for /images, /stylesheets and /javascript? Any idea why? Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated! The terminal output is below.

```
user-MacBook-Pro:projectfolder myuser$ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git master"
    command finished in 1700ms
  * executing "if [ -d /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 9d2c784bafe0f8bd15f831f2ec722b215191e6fa && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q ssh://git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 9d2c784bafe0f8bd15f831f2ec722b215191e6fa; fi"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'if [ -d /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 9d2c784bafe0f8bd15f831f2ec722b215191e6fa && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q ssh://git@server.example.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && cd /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 9d2c784bafe0f8bd15f831f2ec722b215191e6fa; fi'
    command finished in 1344ms
    copying the cached version to /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005
  * executing "cp -RPp /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005 && (echo 9d2c784bafe0f8bd15f831f2ec722b215191e6fa > /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/REVISION)"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'cp -RPp /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/cached-copy /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005 && (echo 9d2c784bafe0f8bd15f831f2ec722b215191e6fa > /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/REVISION)'
    command finished in 945ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'chmod -R g+w /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005'
    command finished in 921ms
  * executing "rm -rf /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/log /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/system /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/tmp/pids &&\\\n      mkdir -p /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public &&\\\n      mkdir -p /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/tmp"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'rm -rf /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/log /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/system /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/tmp/pids &&\
    [project.example.ca] mkdir -p /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public &&\
    [project.example.ca] mkdir -p /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/tmp'
    command finished in 920ms
  * executing "ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/system /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/system"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/system /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/system'
    command finished in 922ms
  * executing "ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/log /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/log"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/log /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/log'
    command finished in 920ms
  * executing "ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/pids /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/shared/pids /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/tmp/pids'
    command finished in 922ms
  * executing "find /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/images /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/stylesheets /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201202250250.11 {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] env TZ=UTC rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'find /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/images /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/stylesheets /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201202250250.11 {} '\'';'\''; true'
*** [err :: project.example.ca] find:
*** [err :: project.example.ca] `/usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/images'
*** [err :: project.example.ca] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: project.example.ca] 
*** [err :: project.example.ca] find:
*** [err :: project.example.ca] `/usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/stylesheets'
*** [err :: project.example.ca] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: project.example.ca] 
*** [err :: project.example.ca] find:
*** [err :: project.example.ca] `/usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005/public/javascripts'
*** [err :: project.example.ca] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: project.example.ca] 
    command finished in 1027ms
  * executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing `deploy:symlink'
[Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.
  * executing "rm -f /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/current && ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005 /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/current"
    servers: ["project.example.ca"]
    [project.example.ca] executing command
    [project.example.ca] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.2-p290@project' -c 'rm -f /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/current && ln -s /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/releases/20120225025005 /usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/current'
    command finished in 814ms
 ** transaction: commit
  * executing `deploy:restart'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add `set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false` to your deploy file. By default it's set to true and it runs a touch command on all your images/javascripts/stylesheets but it's no longer needed if you're using the asset pipeline.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That solved most of the errors! Do you happen to know how I should go about solving the symlink error? [Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.

Comment: My deploy file seems to be too long for the comments box, and I can't self answer my question for another 7 hours, so I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469456/symlink-error-during-rails-app-deploy-with-capistrano