# symlink warning during rails app deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm confused by a warning I'm getting while trying to deploy my rails app with capistrano. The warning is as follows: [Deprecation Warning] This API has changed, please hook deploy:create_symlink instead of deploy:symlink

Can anyone explain to me me what capistrano is trying to do? And how to fix this? Any help would be hugely appreciate!

Oh, and this is my deploy file.

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.

set :application, "Project"

set :scm, "git"
set :repository,  "ssh://git@server.project.ca/usr/local/git_root/project.git"
set :user, "deploy"

#set :rvm_bin_path, "/usr/local/rvm/bin"
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-1.9.2-p290@project"
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :branch, "master"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_to, "/usr/local/www/sites/project.example.ca/public/"

set :use_sudo, false

set :domain, 'project.example.ca'

role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true
```

Comment: You say you're getting an error, but then the message states it is a warning—which is it?

Comment: Sorry. You're right, it's just a warning (I've changed my question). But I wonder if it might have something to do with why my app isn't deploying.

Comment: A deprecation warning shouldn't cause any problems, it's just a heads-up that the feature being used will be removed/changed in a future version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It must be an apache problem them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

also ran into this warning today. agree with andrew, the warning probably isn't your issue (if your deploy file had hooks into deploy:symlink, that warning would be a concern).

if you're still interested in what capistrano is trying to do, looks like this is a change in version 2.11.2 to ensure deploy:symlink gives a deprecation warning: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/164